# Are there any dangers to adding all security protocols in .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, security, tls1.2

I've recently installed a .NET 4 application that doesn't seem to have the TLS1.2 security protocol. The server on which I installed this application supports TLS 1.2 and I'd like to use the installed application with this security protocol. 
I learned that I can add TLS 1.2 support by adding a App_code folder in the folder where the application is installed and added some simple start up code that just runs this line:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I added the OR as to not turn off the original security protocols. My question is, is there any danger to doing this? I feel that it's a good thing that I turned on TLS1.2, but I am wary of just adding code.

Additionally, in my own application, would there be any danger to adding such a line in the startup code?

Comment: The danger is not in what you add, it is what you forget to *remove*.  Like Ssl3, compromised beyond repair by the POODLE attack.  Still, that can only go wrong if the other party unwisely uses SSL3 as well.  Best advice is to not be that party.

Comment: @HansPassant So, in the end, what I'm doing wouldn't be dangerous, right? The clients and servers pick the best protocol they can each support, right?

Comment: Being sloppy about security practices is dangerous.   You are being sloppy by not intentionally disabling protocols that are compromised.  That is dangerous.

Comment: @HansPassant Good point. Unfortunately our customers also require us to use older security protocols. Turning off these old protocols isn't a decision that is up to me, but to management, unfortunately. Thank you for your advice!